# como hacer que los hijos del scrollview se ajuste a cada pantalla? android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estuve tratando de configurar que los hijos del `scrollview` se ajusten a la pantalla, pero no logre nada probando configurar como `match parent` pero se reduce y no se muestra en el dispositivo. Dejo una imagen de cómo se ve y el código del `layout`.

[image: scrollview]

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/img_vid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_detail_img"
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/megaboton" />

            <com.theoplayer.android.api.THEOplayerView
                android:id="@+id/videoPresentacion"
                android:layout_width="360dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp">

            </com.theoplayer.android.api.THEOplayerView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede integrar la imagen dentro de un LinerLayout con match parent, de esta forma el layout que contiene la imagen se ajustara al Spinner. Puedes jugar con el gravity y los margenes para que te quede centrada.

Te recomiendo [este canal de Youtbe](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCG1aEPR4NO2Sd_mmJFimfQQ), tiene mucha info sobre material design.

Espero te sirva de ayuda, saludos.